# Can I run a exported datafusion pipeline through dataproc directly?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-data-fusion

I was having a concurrency issue (running multiple pipelines at the same time) and hence would like to run my exported pipelines (json) directly from dataproc. Is there any tutorial or a script to help me do so?

Any help or leads would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If your pipeline contains a dataproc job, you will need to extract that job info and [create](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/submit-job#submitting_a_job) a dataproc job create request.

There is no feature to extract only dataproc jobs from a datafusion pipeline.